# posix multithread.With Multiple threas using one socket to receive data , when will the data be taken away from recv buffer?

Tags: multithreading, posix

I use multuple thread to receive data from one socket. they all can receive the same data. I want to know when the data will be taken away from recv buffer? Why does not one thread  receive the next data when former thread read former data.

```
pthread_create(&(ntid[i]), NULL, find_host, (void *)&start_addr);

int find_host(void * arg)
{
int sockfd;
unsigned long ip ;
tv.tv_sec = 0;
tv.tv_usec = 100000;
struct sockaddr_in from;
char sendpacket[PACKET_SIZE];
char recvpacket[PACKET_SIZE];
ip = *(unsigned long *)arg;
struct sockaddr_in present_addr;
if( (sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_RAW,protocol->p_proto) )<0)
{      
    perror("socket error");
    exit(1);
}

setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVBUF,&size,sizeof(size) );
if(setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &tv, sizeof(tv))<0){
    printf("socket option  SO_RCVTIMEO not support\n");
    return;
    }
bzero(&present_addr,sizeof(present_addr));
present_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
present_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(ip);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

printf("PING (%s): %d bytes data in ICMP packets.\n",
                    inet_ntoa(present_addr.sin_addr),ICMP_DATA_LEN);
send_packet(sockfd, sendpacket, present_addr);
recv_packet(sockfd, recvpacket, from);
close(sockfd);
}

void recv_packet(int sockfd, char * recvpacket, struct sockaddr_in from)
{       int n,from_len;
    extern int errno;
    int nreceived = 0;
    struct timeval recv_time;

    from_len = sizeof(from);
    while (nreceived < MAX_SEND_TIMES)
    {    
            if((n=recvfrom(sockfd,recvpacket, PACKET_SIZE, 0,
                            (struct sockaddr *)&from,&from_len)) <0)
            {   
                if(errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno== EAGAIN )
                {
                    printf("recvfrom Timeout!!!!\n");
                    pthread_exit(NULL);
                }    
            }


            gettimeofday(&recv_time,NULL);

            if (1 == unpack(recv_time, recvpacket, n, from))
            {
                printf(" find  %u\n", (unsigned short)pthread_self());
                nreceived++;
            }
            else
                printf(" not find\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide some details on `send_packet()` and `recv_packet()`?

Comment: @MichaelBurr added recv

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're seeing?  Are you wondering why one thread seems to receive all the data or is it something else?  You should give some information about what behavior you're seeing and how it's different from what you expect to see. Or something along those lines.

Comment: when a message comes,I wonder why all threads can receive it in the same time. @MichaelBurr

Comment: I expect one thread receive a message other threads after will receive next message,but other threads after it receive the same message. @MichaelBurr

Comment: Are you using multiple sockets or the same socket for each thread?

Comment: Multiple sockets @usr

Comment: As I understand it a raw socket allows you to sniff all network traffic. Each socket must be independent, then, because different applications would steal each others packets if packets were not made available to all sockets. That would not be a good design. So as you can see it is by design that each socket reads all data.

Comment: @wangsquirrel: you you have a complete program I can play around with (either pasted into the question or somewhere like github or ideone)?  I'd like to try somethings out, but don't want to have to fill in the blanks in the code if I can avoid it.